# Selenium python click button w\ partial ID

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote some python code that logs in automatically on outlook, and writes emails and send them. The problem is that the button 'Write new email' is identified on the script online as *_ariaId_* followed by any random number between 1 and 999. Therefore on that part of my script I have

```
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "_ariaId_")]')
nextButton.click()
```

But for some reason it tells me that it cannot find it.

Comment: keep html snippet for that element

Comment: for write a new mail button i have seen id 'CommandBar580New messageAdd' try this by `driver.find_element_by_id('CommandBar580New messageAdd').click()`

Comment: can you share the html for new email button?

Answer (score 1):

The following code may work for you.

```
newEmailButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'New mail')]")
newEmailButton.click();

sendButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'SEND')]")
sendButton.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  **xpath** :

```
//span[normalize-space()='Nuovo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="label o365buttonLabel _fce_r _fce_n" id="_ariaId_26">Nuovo</span>
```

That's what I need to identify, that ariaId which changes everytime.